# how to remove hyperlink from contentflow.js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php

this is the link of jquery plugin which i am using in asp.net page.

when i click on the image of contentflow it shows the image in the next page so my requirement is to remove that link.

so how i can remove that link from the contentflow.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment this line in contentflow.js
window.location.href=A

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look in the contentflow.js file for the place where it creates a hyperlink using the image that you've clicked on.

Once you've found that, you can modify the source code so that it doesn't create a link at all, but just displays the image.

Comment: i found the solution by commenting this line in contentflow.js file Window.location.href=A

Answer (score 0):

there is a canvas element used to show the picture. Using chrome`s developers tolls, I`ve noticed that the canvas element has a click event handler attached. So I`m guessing that if you remove the click event handler, the link will be removed also.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('.content portray').unbind('click');
       // removes/detaches any click events from the elements with 'content portray' 
       //class. Because the canvas has this class.
 });
```

Comment: where to write this line in contentflow.js file. i entered this line at the end of the contentflow.js file but it is not working.

Comment: see my edited answer... maybe with the document ready... and one more thing... use jQuery instead of $, because I`ve seen that also prototype framework is used.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.content portray').unbind('click'); 
        }); i tried this but still not working.

Comment: i found the solution by commenting this line in contentflow.js file Window.location.href=A

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without having to modify the default ContentFlow behavior is to override the `onclickActiveItem` event in the ContentFlow options, eg:

```
var flow = new ContentFlow('MyContentFlowDivID',
{
    onclickActiveItem: function(item) {

    //empty function overrides default behavior
    }
});
```